# knockout filter doesn't works right

Tags: html, knockout.js, filter

I have this knockout view

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
if (data != null) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { UsuarioPersonals: UsuarioPersonalMapping }, 
self);
    }
var self = this;
self.UsuarioPersonals = ko.observableArray();
self.search_UsuarioPersonals = ko.observable(''); 



var UsuarioPersonalsUri = '/api/UsuarioPersonals/';


function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.error(errorThrown);
    });
}

function getAllUsuarioPersonals() {
    ajaxHelper(UsuarioPersonalsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.UsuarioPersonals(data);
    });
}



self.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.UsuarioPersonals(), function (rec) {
        return (
            (self.search_UsuarioPersonals().length == 0 || rec.Email().toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search_UsuarioPersonals().toLowerCase()) > -1)
        )
    });
});  


   var UsuarioPersonalsDetail = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data != null) {
            self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
            self.Email = ko.observable(data.Email);
            self.Password = ko.observable(data.Password);

        }
    }


    var UsuarioPersonalMapping = {
        create: function (options) {
            return new UsuarioPersonalsDetail(options.data);
        }
    };

// Fetch the initial data.
getAllUsuarioPersonals();


};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

and html page where i want records be filtered by email field.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    email:   <input data-bind="value: search_UsuarioPersonals, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /><br />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Filtro</h2>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredRecords">
                <!-- <tr><td> Nombre contiene: <input data-bind=" value:=" valueupdate: ="" /></td></tr>-->
                <!--<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredRecords">-->
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Password"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

what is wrong that the filtered results show correctly? So data get from server are filtered with Email field. Everytime page is loaded, all datafield are put in is right data-bind but when i write a value in the input field nothing happen.

Comment: Reduce your sample code to the absolute minimum that is required to demonstrate the issue. 90% of the code you show is visual clutter and has nothing to do with the problem. Try to stay lower than 10 lines of code.

Comment: I thinks is really the minimum, only observables and functions that are in relationship with the issue (mapping date too). Thanks.

Comment: Take out all of the Ajax code, it is of no consequence to your problem. In exchange, initialize the viewmodel with sample data that helps demonstrates the issue. Your child viewmodel does not need 3 properties when 2 of them don't play a role in the issue. Finally, make your code sample runnable (Stack Overflow has a feature similar to JSFiddle, use it). See [mcve].

Comment: My point is that it's much easier for any reader to understand the issue when they don't have to mentally filter out code that is not connected to the problem. This includes people who answer, but *much more importantly* this includes people who have a similar problem and come here via a web search. Think of the next person and strip your code down to the real core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your ajax call returns you are setting UsuarioPeronals equal to the raw data. The data has no observable properties they are just text, so your filter function throws an error when it tries to use Email with parenthesis like it's an observable (`... || rec.Email().toLowerCase()...`).

```
function getAllUsuarioPersonals() {
    ajaxHelper(UsuarioPersonalsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.UsuarioPersonals(data);
    });
}
```

You'll need to use the same `UsuarioPersonalMapping` on it that you reference at the top of your viewmodel or loop through the data returned and create a new `UsuarioPersonalsDetail` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when computed is called, the `self.UsuarioPersonals()` does not have data. Can you use observableArray instead of computed ? or computed is the requirement?

Comment: Is needed because to re evaluate function when search item is changed (search_UsuarioPersonals) Thanks for your reply.

Comment: please reffer this --- 

deferEvaluation — Optional. If this option is true, then the value of the computed observable will not be evaluated until something actually attempts to access its value or manually subscribes to it. By default, a computed observable has its value determined immediately during creation.

Ref - https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html

Mark deferEvaluation as true, not sure but this can resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i did this change, but same result. If i looks inside Chrome developers i see same error:" rec.Email() is not a function.